# The pigpio C library can't be loaded on this machine and any | | attempt to use it will fail. Error: "Module did not self-register"

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, ubuntu-22.04, pigpio

I try to work with GPIO with nodejs function but got warning:

```
Warning: The pigpio C library can't be loaded on this machine and any 
attempt to use it will fail.                                          
                                                                   
Error: "Module did not self-register"                                 
                                                                    
If you are working on a Raspberry Pi and see a "Module did not self-  
register" error, this typically indicates that the installation       
instructions were not exactly followed. For further details see the   
installation section of the readme at                                 
https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio#installation                          
Note that step 1 of the installation instructions must be completed   
before step 2.
```

and errror:

```
Invoking require('bindings')('pigpio.node') resulted in the following error:

Error: /snap/core/current/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not 
found (required by /usr/local/lib/libpigpio.so.1)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
at bindings (/home/pi/GIT/node/hello/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at /home/pi/GIT/node/hello/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:8:31
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/GIT/node/hello/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:43:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

my `node` version and location are:
`v14.20.1`
`/snap/bin/nodenode`

`pigpiod`:

`79`
`/usr/local/bin/pigpiod`

`npm pigpio` version from `package-lock.json`

```
"pigpio": {
      "version": "3.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/pigpio/-/pigpio-3.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-z7J55K14IwWkA+oW5JHzWcgwThFAuJ7IzV3A2//yRm4jJ2DTU0DHIy91DB0siOi12rvvlrIhRetEuAo0ztF/vQ==",
      "requires": {
        "bindings": "^1.5.0",
        "nan": "^2.14.2"
      }
},
```

Does node not see pigpiod installed on the machine?

Comment: Why not use `libgpiod`? The one you are trying to use is non-standard, non-portable. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libgpiod